# In Log/Text file check same id Occur again Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, powershell, logging, vbscript

I'm working in a MNC company, and I want to automate a manual process using Batch Script(2nd alternative Powerscript/VB Script) so please help me out.

**Problem Description:**
An application create log file daily with name of that day date(Ex. 20140804.LOG), and contains Batch_Id in form of incremented 7 digit format(Ex. Batch_Id = 1234567, Batch_Id = 1234568).
We have to monitor string Batch_Id in current day log file if same Batch_Id comes more than one times then there is problem else OK.
I want to make a batch script which check this in interval of 30 Minutes, and print in CMD prompt "problem" or "OK"

I had put my full effort to make it but couldn't get success.

Please Help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: 'I had put my full effort to make it but couldn't get success.' -Please show what you tried, and where you had issues with it.

Comment: Hi again,
I am very new to batch script so couldn't play with batch script as expert do.
I google for similar script and found script which search for duplicate text like '@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=test.txt
for /F "Delims=" %%i in (%file%) do (
    set read-array=!read-array:;%%i=!;%%i
)
rem del %file%
for %%i in (%read-array%) do (
    echo %%i
    rem echo %%i
)'

But my problem is little bit different :

Comment: But my problem is little bit different :
1) Take input log file as their date name 
2) Search Duplicate string Starting with "Batch_Id = "
3) If found duplicate print alert problem

Thanks  Bond,TheMadTechnician for quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2 :**

Assuming that the structure is the same as in the snippet :

```
@echo off
echo Working !!!
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.log ^| findstr "Queue_ID"') do (
   set $Line=%%a
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=^=," %%b in ('echo !$Line!') do (
      set $Value=%%b
      set $Value=#Queue_id!$Value: =!
      if not defined !$Value! (set !$Value!=1) else (echo Error with [!$Value!]) 
))
endlocal
echo Done !!!
Pause
```

Comment: Hi sachadee,
Firstly I want to thanks you.

Your script did good job, but there is a problem,In log file string "Batch_Id = 1234567" in some where middle and for duplicate your script comparing for whole line, not the string

Comment: Give a snippet of your log

Comment: [2014-08-04 00:20:59]: KSDPrintAdmin_NO : Documents printed ok
[2014-08-04 00:20:59]: KSDPrintAdmin_NO : RunOnce(): Batch_ID = 7691989, USERID = KSD, and DEPARTMENT = 032861
[2014-08-04 00:20:59]: KSDPrintAdmin_NO : RunOnce(): Variable CheckDepartments loaded from INI file: 032103,032844,032861,032862,032863,032864,032865,032874,032882,032970

Comment: Formatting is not showing in comment.

In log new line starts from like string    [2014-08-04 00:20:49]:

Comment: Thanks, Very close but still Facing little problem, Its showing many "error with" while string is different. I am attaching the log file in url [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByEtsyft3LhENGFXNDFzckxKZ1U/edit?usp=sharing), please verify it your own end.
Note: in log file batch_id written as Queue_Id

Comment: Corrected try it again.

Comment: Would you please explain the solution a little bit

Comment: In your logfile you have some other QUEUE_ID but they are all Upper case. So i just make a literal (case sensitive) without `/i` switch `findstr` against the string `Queue_ID` to get the good value. You see how it is important to detail your question and give some good snippet and information. Don't forget it for the next time...

Comment: hi again, I want a string which concat all error [!$Value!] in a String and then want to use that String to send in mail body.
Do you know any way to do this !!